# Arduino Leonardo Key Detector

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I want to make an arduino code on the arduino leonardo that detects when keys are being pressed and to print them to the serial monitor so I can control the arduino with the computer keyboard. I need to know how to detect keyboard presses.

Comment: Do you want to plug a keyboard on the Arduino?

Comment: I want to connect the arduino to a computer with a keyboard connected to the computer.

Comment: you need another program running on the PC that will catch key presses and push them to a serial port. I think most languages can handle this natively or with common used modules. You can just type into the serial monitor to, without any other software, but i assume you want to catch special key presses from other places than the serial monitor...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If the keyboard is plugged to the computer, there is no way the Arduino
can detect the key presses. You can, however, run a program on the
computer that detects those key presses and forwards that information to
the Arduino.

That being said, if you goal is simply to “control the Arduino with the
computer keyboard”, I suggest you run a [terminal emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) on the
computer. This is a program that emulates an old school computer
terminal, like the classic [VT100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) series. You won't get individual key
events this way: only characters. For example, if you press and hold
<kbd>Shift</kbd>, then press <kbd>A</kbd>, then release both, the
Arduino will receive a single `'A'` character through the serial port,
instead of four individual key events.

On Windows, you can try [Putty](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/). On macOS and Linux, you already have
a terminal emulator: you just need a communication program such as
[picocom](https://github.com/npat-efault/picocom) to connect it to the serial port.

You could also use the Arduino serial monitor. This is, however, not a
proper terminal emulator. Specifically, it doesn't send the characters
you type immediately: you have to click on “Send” for that.